# Получение списка компьютеров в локальной сети

Tags: c#, lan

Как мне получить список ip адресов,mac адресов и учетных записей компьютеров в локальной сети?

Comment: 1. Думаю можно запросить с таблиц WMI. 2. Возможно ActiveDirectory (если в домене)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По своей сути это три разных задачи, близких друг к другу по смыслу.

Чтобы получить список адресов сети, можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
public void GetLocalAddress()
{
    // доступно ли сетевое подключение
    if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        return;
    // запросить у DNS-сервера IP-адрес, связанный с именем узла
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    // Пройдем по списку IP-адресов, связанных с узлом
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        // если текущий IP-адрес версии IPv4, то выведем его 
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
        }
    }        
}
```

Это для консольного приложения, но можно использовать где угодно, просто заменив  `Console.WriteLine`. Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

1. [Метод Dns.GetHostEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Метод Dns.GetHostName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.dns.gethostname(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Свойство IPHostEntry.AddressList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.iphostentry.addresslist(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. [Свойство IPAddress.AddressFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. [Перечисление AddressFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily(v=vs.110).aspx)
6. [Метод NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

С получением списка MAC-адресов дела обстоят так:

```
public void GetMacAddress()
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Или другой способ с помощью `System.Management`:

```
public List<string> GetMacAddress()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();

    List<string> MACAddress = new List<string>();

    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        try
        {
            MACAddress.Add(objMO["MacAddress"].ToString());
            objMO.Dispose(); // а может и не нужно
        }
        catch(Exception) { }
    }
    return MACAddress;
}
```

Полезные ссылки из получения MAC-адресов:

1. [Метод NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Метод NetworkInterface.GetPhysicalAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getphysicaladdress(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Перечисление OperationalStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.operationalstatus(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. Очень полезно: [C# Get Computer's MAC address “OFFLINE”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15784105/5275890)

Получение учетных записей программно - это проблема, которую нужно решать отдельно. Скорее всего так просто не выйдет. К примеру для конкретной машины, на которой будет запущено приложение - можно получить данные учетной записи через `System.Management`, вот так:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher usersSearcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectCollection users = usersSearcher.Get();
```

Пример взят отсюда: [How can I get a list Local Windows Users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750294/5275890). В первом ответе, который принят упоминается о проблемах с брандмауэром и антивирусами, с чем я согласен. Причем учетная запись может быть доменной, а также и локальной. Это отдельный вопрос, требующий особого внимания.

Answer (score 4):

Что бы получить ip и mac можно использовать NetServerEnum и NetApiBufferFree из netapi32.dll - подключается через dllImport. Тем же способом и mac адреса машин. Для учетных записей к сожалению нужен будет либо доступ к домену либо пилить велосипед в виде клиент\сервера которые общаются по UDP. Клиент запускается на машине, данные которой нужно поулчить, после чего шлет всю инфу на определенный сервер (будут проблемки с антивирусами или брандмауэром, но если нужно только для своей сетки, вопрос вполне решаемый).